# How to set timeout for anonoymous block or query in plsql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I know you can set user [profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914286/oracle-set-query-timeout) or set a general timeout for query.

But I wish to set timeout to a specific query inside a procedure and catch the exception, something like :

```
begin
      update tbl set col = v_val; --Unlimited time
      delete from tbl where id = 20; --Unlimited time

      begin
            delete from tbl; -- I want this to have a limited time to perform
            exception  when (timeout???) then
            --code; 

      end;

end;
```

Is this possible? is there any timeout exceptions at all I can catch? per block or query? didn't find much info on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not set a timeout in pl/sql. You could use a host language for this in which you embed your sql and pl/sql.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
select * from tbl for update wait 10; --This example will wait 10 seconds.  Replace 10 with number of seconds to wait
```

Then, the select will attempt to lock the specified rows, but if it's unsuccessful after n seconds, it will throw an "ORA-30006: resource busy; acquire with WAIT timeout expired".  If lock is achieved, then you can execute your delete.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea :  you could do the Delete in a **DBMS_JOB**.
Then create a procedure to monitor the job, which then calls :

```
DBMS_JOB.BROKEN(JOBID,TRUE);
DBMS_JOB.remove(JOBID);
```

Comment: Just be prepared that the session running this job does not terminate immediately. It must first rollback all the changes made. The rollback may take more time than the update/delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
v_timer1 := dbms_utility.get_time();

  WHILE TRUE 
  LOOP

    v_timer2 := dbms_utility.get_time();

    EXIT WHEN (ABS(v_timer1 - v_timer2)/100) > 60;  -- cancel after 60 sec.
  END LOOP;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

```
MariaDB> select sleep(4);
+----------+
| sleep(4) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (4.002 sec)

MariaDB>
```

See: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sleep/

Comment: This isn't a MariaDB question.