# can I set a time out when calling procedure using DBLink Pl/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am running several procedures and functions from another DB and I am calling them over DBLink, but sometimes the requests take too much time which case problems on my own DB and the server which the request has been made from. noting that I am a normal user and not SYS admin, so I cannot create profile.
so is there a way to set timeout for the request over DBLink?

Comment: No I don't think the is any such option for specific calls. You could use general limits in a profile, but they will effect you connections in general.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519192/how-to-set-timeout-for-anonoymous-block-or-query-in-plsql

Comment: thank you but I am not sysadmin, also I don't want to restrict for all my connections, it is one or two procedure that are causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set timeout for single procedure. If you have host application, you can however set Timeout interval in it.