# Terminate a running sub procedure call

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure which will call another procedure, but sometime the sub-procedure takes more than 2 mins or more to complete. I trying to find a way to:

- terminate the called sub-procedure if it is still running after 20 seconds
- or force the sub-procedure `RETURN` to the caller procedure after 20 seconds

Is there any way to do achieve this?

**Caller Function :**

```
 IF .... THEN ...
   l_result := PKG_B.TRXN_PROC (PI_QUOT_NUM => pi_quot_num );    
END IF;
```

Comment: What Oracle version are you using? (In 18c, Oracle introduced a mechanism to cancel a running SQL statement)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set timeout for anonoymous block or query in plsql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519192/how-to-set-timeout-for-anonoymous-block-or-query-in-plsql)

Comment: Hi Frank, we are using 12c only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option might  be to run the procedure as a background job using `dbms_scheduler`, sleep for 20 seconds and then terminate the job.

```
dbms_scheduler.run_job('MY_JOB_NAME');
DBMS_LOCK.sleep(seconds => '20');
SELECT STATE INTO v_state FROM USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS
   WHERE JOB_NAME = 'MY_JOB_NAME';
IF v_state = 'RUNNING' THEN
   dbms_scheduler.STOP_JOB(job_name=>'MY_JOB_NAME',force=>true);
END IF;
```

This is just to give you an idea and not a fully functional code. It is recommended to add further checks/ exceptions if required. It's also advisable to check every second in a loop or so instead of waiting for *full 20*, the choice is with you.

Following grants may be required to the user running it.

```
grant create job , manage scheduler to your_user;
grant execute on dbms_lock to your_user;
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `user_scheduler_jobs` instead of `dba_scheduler_jobs`. You don't need additional privileges to query that view, and `dba_scheduler_jobs` might contain another user's job with the same name (so if you use this view, you should add an additional where clause to filter by job owner).

Comment: @Frank Schmitt : I agree.

Comment: @Kaushik and Frank, thanks for giving me the possible way to go. I will try to rewrite my code using user_scheduler_jobs.